# AngularJS view not rendered with data received in a service using routeparams

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I am trying to show single trail information on trailDetails.html when I click this link on my searchTrails.html. And there is nothing on trailDetails.html. But if I move codes in getDataService.js to searchTrailsController.js, everything will be ok. I don't figure out why. Could anybody give some suggestions?

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("crowd", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",{
        templateUrl:"views/searchTrails.html",
        controller:"searchTrailsCtrl"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/trails/:trailId", {
        templateUrl: "views/trailDetails.html",
        controller: "searchTrailsCtrl"
    });
})
```

getDataService.js:

```
app.service("dataService", function ($http, $routeParams){
this.getSingleTrail = function (){
    var trail = [];
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/DMW-skeleton-1.0/trail/findTrailByTrailId/" + $routeParams.trailId)
    .success(function (data){
        trail.push(data);
    })
    return trail
}})
```

searchTrailsController.js:

```
app.controller("searchTrailsCtrl", function ($scope, dataService ) {
$scope.trail = dataService.getSingleTrail();})
```

But there comes nothing in trailDetails.html:

```
<p>{{trail.trailInfo.trailDescription}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your data coming asynchronously but you try save them synchronously. 
Step by step:

1. You define variable trail = []
2. You return trail variable to controller
3. Server responds with data (but you already return trail)

You can solve this problem by using next code:

```
app.service("dataService", function ($http, $routeParams){
this.getSingleTrail = function (){
    var trail = [];
    return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/DMW-skeleton-1.0/trail/findTrailByTrailId/" + $routeParams.trailId);
}})


app.controller("searchTrailsCtrl", function ($scope, dataService ) {
    $scope.trail;
  dataService.getSingleTrail().success(function(data){
    $scope.trail = data;
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks!That works perfectly for me. That means putting data into variables must be written in controller.js. And the service.js is just used to put URLs in? Forgive me that I am just new in AngularJS. I used to put those codes getting data only in controller.js. But I want to share some data among different controllers, so I began to use service.

Comment: That means I can just write `this.trail = data` in service.js?